# jQuery .prop() compatibility

Tags: jquery, version, compatibility, prop

I'm trying to test if the `.prop()` method exists on the current jQuery included (for compatibility reason) via:

```
if(typeof $.prop === 'function')
```

I would expect that the condition above is `true` for `jQuery >= 1.6` and `false` for `jQuery < 1.6` as I can understand from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Anyway, testing this on jsfiddle, leads to:

`typeof $.prop === 'function'` is:

- `true` when `jQuery >= 1.6`
- `false` when `jQuery < 1.6 and jQuery > 1.3`
- `true` when `jQuery <= 1.3`

[**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6SLv/) is the very very simple script which provide the results above (just switch jQuery version to see what I've described).

When I try to use that `.prop()` with jQuery i.e. 1.3 I get the `.prop is not a function` error.
The same problem occours also testing outside jsfiddle.
Is it normal such a behavior?
How could I truly test if `.prop()` is available?

Thanks

Comment: i did test it on FF4, Safari5 and Chrome12

Comment: Why support 1.3. It's really old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`alert(typeof $.fn.prop === 'function')`

You want to check for the `.prop` method on the jQuery prototype which lives on `$.fn`. This is false in 1.3.

Also I would avoid feature detection for jQuery versions and instead support a particular version (and up).

Answer (score 6):

What I did, is build a compatible function for prop, for jQuery versions, which doesn't use prop:

```
(function($){
    if (typeof $.fn.prop !== 'function')
    $.fn.prop = function(name, value){
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            return this.attr(name);
        } else {
            return this.attr(name, value);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can test this code: http://jsfiddle.net/JtK2Q

Answer (score 4):

You're checking for the existence of a *static* method.

You need to check for the instance method by writing `$.fn.prop` (`$.fn` is the same as `$.prototype`).

Comment: It's the same as `$.fn.init.prototype`